# Is one graph ever a subgraph of another?

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ denote the complete equipartite graph with $p$ partitions and $v$ vertices in each partition; that is, $G:= K_{v,v, \dots ,v}$ where there are $p$ instances of $v$ in the subscript.
>
> Let $H$ denote any induced subgraph of $G$ on $v+1$ vertices such that these $v+1$ vertices are only contained in at most $p-1$ of the partitions.
>
> Prove that $H$ is never contained in the complement of $G$.

It is easy to prove for $v=1,2$, and appears to be true for $v=3$, but I cannot prove it for $v>2$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement $G'$ of $G$ is the disjoint union of $p$ copies of $K_v$; in particular, $G'$ does not contain a copy of $K_{v+1}$. If $H$ has at most one vertex in each part of $G$, $H$ is isomorphic to $K_{v+1}$, so $G'$ does not contain a copy of $H$. We may assume, then, that $H$ has distinct vertices $x$ and $y$ in the same part of $G$. That part of $G$ has only $v$ vertices, however, so $H$ must have a third vertex, $z$, in a different part of $G$.

Suppose that $H'$ is an isomorphic copy of $H$ contained in the complement of $G$, and let $x',y'$, and $z'$ be the vertices of $H'$ corresponding to $x,y$, and $z$, respectively, in $H$. There is no edge between $x$ and $y$ in $H$, so there can be no edge between $x'$ and $y'$ in $H'$; thus, $x'$ and $y'$ must be in different copies of $K_v$. There are edges in $H$ from $x$ to $zw$ and from $y$ to $z$, so there must be edges in $H'$ from $x'$ to $z'$ and from $y'$ to $z'$. Get a contradiction by considering where $z'$ can be.